# Understand Typescript Pick

Tags: typescript

My simplified code looks like this.

```
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
let a : Todo = {
  title: "title",
  description: "bla bla",
  completed: false
}

 type TodoPreview = Pick<Todo, "title" | "completed">;

 const todoPreview: TodoPreview = a ;
 console.log(todoPreview); // why todoPreview has  description property?
```

why **todoPreview** has **description** property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because although it's type only has `title` and `completed`, the **object itself** has an additional property (`description`). `todoPreview` and `a` both point to the **same object**, which has `title`, `description`, and `completed`. The assignment `todoPreview = a` doesn't make a copy, it just points the `todoPreview` constant at the same object `a` points to.

In memory, you start out with:

```
                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a:Ref55461−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>| (object)               |
                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                           | title: "title"         |
                           | description: "bla bla" |
                           | completed: false       |
                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then after `const todoPreview: TodoPreview = a;` you have:

```
a:Ref55461−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                       |
                       |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                       +−−>| (object)               |
                       |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                       |   | title: "title"         |
todoPreview:Ref55461−−−+   | description: "bla bla" |
                           | completed: false       |
                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Even though you've given the const `todoPreview` the type `TodoPreview`, that doesn't affect the object itself.

Comment: Maybe to add, its just a compile-time promise. It promises that it has 'title' and 'completed' available. It may have more, but only those you can rely on. You cant do `todoPreview.description` for example, because it has not been agreed upon that `description` is available.

Comment: @Caramiriel should the compiler not throw any error stating,   it's unassignable?

Comment: @JohnDoe - No, because an object can be a *subtype* of a type, and a subtype can add properties. So it's perfectly valid for a `TodoPreview` to have a `description` (or `foo` or `bar`) property. The type defines the interface you have to the object, but the object itself can be more than that interface. The only place TypeScript would complain about an extra property would be `const x: TodoPreview = {title: "a", complete: false, description: "bla"};` in which case it would complain about extra properties on the object literal. That's a special case error for a common mistake.

Comment: @JohnDoe no, since `const todoPreview: TodoPreview = a` creates a new variable `todoPreview` pointing to `a`, and it requires both fields to be available (as per the `TodoPreview` type). `a` does have that, so the compiler allows you to do so. Its not a strict interface. It can have more fields.

Comment: More about excess property checks [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). (That page says it's obsolete, but the replacement page doesn't yet describe excess property checks. The documentation is in the process of being overhauled.)